# Plot of a 2-dimensional parameter space with R

Tags: r

With Mathematica I made a plot. 
With R this plot can be made to look more elegant, I guess.

How can I make such a plot in R?

[image: Mathematica plot]

It is about the function M_{\pm}

```
M^2_\pm = \frac{y \pm \sqrt{14x + 6xy + y^2}}{2x}
```

The following is show on the plot

- The curve M^2_+ = M_-
- The curve M^2_+ = 0
- The curve M^2_- = 0
- The shaded region where both M^2_+ and M^2_- > 0
- Some points with text

In the new plot

- The axes should be on the outside of the plot as is usual in R
- I would welcome a more elegant alternative for the text and the arrows in the pictures

P.S. With the help pages of R I tried to make such a plot, but I didn't get beyond the basic use of plot and curve.

**Update** Maybe contour can do the job

Comment: In the world of plots, that looks pretty good to me as it stands. Many textbooks and papers include plots that don't look that good.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
f <- function(x,y){x*y}
x <- seq(0.2,2,length=1000)
objective <- 0.5
y <- c()
for(i in 1:length(x)){
  y[i] <- optimize(function(y){abs(f(x[i],y)-objective)},interval=c(0,4))$minimum
}
plot(x,y,type="l")
```

This plot shows where the function x*y=0.5 for x between 0.2 and 2.  This isn't for your particular function, but I hope it's a useful start.  Note that this is very hacky since `optimize` is slow and `for` loops should generally be avoided in R whenever possible.

[image: Plot for f(x,y) = x*y = 0.5]

Comment: Your suggestion works only if the equation f(x,y) = 0.5 has a solution over the full x-range. Try for example f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2. You expect a circle of radius \sqrt{0.5}. However, it also plots the line y=0 for x > \sqrt{0.5}